# JavaScript heap size ever increasing with AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am designing a web application, and the app requires that I use AJAX to navigate pages, so the same frame is static, but the inner content changes, like

```
$(".nav > div").on('click',function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $("#main").load("/page" + id + ".html");
  });
```

which will load page1.html, following me clicking on the element with the id '1', for example.

I then use

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {...javascript...});
```

to run the rest of my script which will be interacting with the inner content. My script contains numerous functions like

```
$('#fade').on('click', function() {
    $('#zoom').removeClass('grow').addClass('shrink');
```

which interact with unqiue id's, all of which are similar in each of the '/page[number].html' files.

My script runs fine if I run it on an entirely static page, but as soon as I start introducing the AJAX element of reloading the html in the inner frame, the website gets slower and slower every time I make an AJAX call - by using the .nav bar - until a crash. The javascript heap size seems to increase almost exponentially, see:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/54UEL.jpg

Not only the js heap size is ever increasing, but it also seems 'paint' is taking up a lot of memory. Each page I am loading a new, fairly high res image, could this be related?

I am fairly new to AJAX calls so any pointers would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: You can use `$(document).on('click', '#fade', function () {...});` instead of `$('#fade').on('click', function() {...});` and thus apply the function to the elements that are yet to be added to the page, so you don't need to bind these functions on the `ajaxComplete` callback. Not sure if it would have any impact on the performance, anyway.

Comment: @DineiA.Rockenbach It should have a decent effect on performance as there will only be 1 event handler instead of a handler for each event on every single required element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that you're creating event handlers with `$().on` on the other pages and you aren't explicitly removing them before you navigate to another page.

```
$(element).on(event, function() {
  // ...
});
```

When you make an event listener like this jQuery maintains a reference to the function, meaning it can't be garbage collected. Every time you navigate to a new page, you create more event handlers that can't be automatically removed.

```
function eventHandler() {
  // ...
}

// when the page is loaded
$(element).on(event, eventHandler);

// just before you leave
$(element).off(event, eventHandler);
```

Better still, when you know there only needs to be one interaction with the element before you'll navigate away, you can use `one`, to create an event listener that will be called only once before it is automatically dereferenced.

```
$(element).one(event, eventHandler);
// don't worry about removing these handlers
```

How you structure this code is best determined by your existing application architecture.

Comment: Hi Dan, this is the structure of my code

`head( ajaxComplete -> all script relating to elements)
body( html to be replaced )`
Unbinding everything just before calling my AJAX seems to stop the functionality of the site all together after I navigate once.
Is your answer assuming I have JS in page1.html for example, because I don't

Comment: You only need to unbind the events that affect the page that you are navigating away from. So long as you're only doing that, it should remove anything from any other pages.

Answer (score 0):

You need to unbind the events. If not, you are binding and binding events to your element instead of override it. You can do it with `$('#yourElement').unbind('click');`